# Removing unwanted text from a program

Tags: java

Can you help "de-bug" this program. 
I have it almost perfect but when I print it includes "28" , which I don't want.

```
public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int n)
{
    int lhs=0,rhs = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i<(n-2);i++)
    {
        lhs += i * (n/i)                                                                   ;
        rhs += i * ((n-1)/i)                                                               ;
    }

    rhs += n;
    if(rhs == lhs)
    {
        return true                                                                        ;
    }
    return false                                                                       ;
}


public static void main(String[] theory) {
    int candArray[] = new int [20]                                                 ;
    for(int i = 2;i<21;i++)
    {
        candArray[i-2] = (int) (Math.pow(2, i-1)*(Math.pow(2, i)-1)                   );
    }

    for(int i = 1;i<20;i++){
        if(isPerfectNumber(candArray[i])                                              )
        {
            System.out.println(candArray[i] + " is a perfectNumber"                       );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly (more clearly) what you **do** want?

Comment: When I run the program it prints "28 is a perfectNumber". I want everything except 28 is a perfect number.

Comment: 28 is a perfect number. Why do you not want it to be printed?

Comment: I agree 28 sounds perfect.  No debugging needed.

Comment: I don't want to include it. I only want them after 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fastest & simplest change:

```
if(isPerfectNumber(candArray[i]) && candArray[i] > 28 )
{
   System.out.println(candArray[i] + " is a perfectNumber" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Now you're using [Mersenne Primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) to find the [perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). Based on the way you're filling your array of Mersenne Primes, the Mersenne Prime associated with `28` is included. Mersenne Primes are of the form (2^p - 1), your first loop in `main` is storing Mersenne Primes in an array.

You need to figure out:

- Which Mersenne Prime is associated with the perfect number `28`?
- Now how should you change the index in your first loop - **or** your second loop - in `main` to leave out the Mersenne Prime associated with `28`?